# Unable to submit a form with vue.js

Tags: forms, vue.js

I am new to vue.js and this is how i am submitting a form with vue.js,but the form does not submits and i get "?" in the URL as well after submitting the form.

```
<!-- root Element -->
<body id="test">
<!-- My html form -->
<form v-on="submit: send">
    <input>
    <button>Send</button>
</form>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.6/vue.min.js"></script>
<script>
    new Vue({
        el: '#test',
        methods: {
            send: function(e) {
                alert('test');
                e.preventDefault(); 
            }
        }
    })
</script>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Error in syntax/usage `<form v-on="submit: send">` should be this `<form v-on:submit="send">`

Comment: No,i am still unable to submit a form with this syntax @BelminBedak

Comment: I have no idea what you are expecting, but when you submit form it should only show alert http://jsbin.com/sojonidigo/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Your form won't actually submit because when the `send` method is run you're cancelling the submission of the form with `e.preventDefault();`.

Comment: Please have a look at this.
http://jsbin.com/dofiqejedu/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Comment: After commenting //e.preventDefault(); still form doesn't submits. @DanielWaghorn

Comment: Don't mount vue instance to body tag, wrap it in div with id test and it should work

Comment: Here is the example http://jsbin.com/wovuqihapi/edit?html,output

Comment: Thank you its working fine now,can you please let me know what was the reason ?

Comment: As mentioned, you've made 3 mistakes: 
1) v-on="submit: send" -> v-on:submit="send"
2) don't stop submit event if you want to submit form ;)
3) don't use body as root element

Comment: Ok thank you so much for your guidance and time @donMateo

Answer (score 0):

Don't put your `id` on your body since your script is within your body too. Use a `div` instead :

```
<body>
<div id="test">
    <form v-on:submit="send">
        <input>
        <button>Send</button>
    </form>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.6/vue.min.js"></script>
<script>
    new Vue({
        el: '#test',
        methods: {
            send: function(e) {
                alert('test');
                e.preventDefault(); 
            }
        }
    })
</script>
```